# Dealing with large kernel matrix in SVM, Matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, machine-learning, matrix-decomposition

I have a matrix X, size 40x60000

while writing the SVM, I need to form a linear kernel: $K = X^TX$

And of course I would get an error "Requested 60000x60000 (26.8GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference".

How is it usually done? the data set is Mnist, so someone must have done this before. In this case $\text{rank}(K) \leq 40$, I need a way to store K and later pass it to $\texttt{quadprog}$.

Comment: You can create a stripped SVD by appending some string to the command. [S,V,D] = svd(rand(10,2),'stripped') . Since the singular values will be 0 for all dimensions exceeding the smallest we will get away with a $40\times40$ diagonal matrix in the middle.

Comment: such command exists? I know svd (X'*X,'econ'), but then I had the same error, svd(X,'econ) would work though (in fact that's how I reduced size of X to 40x60000)

Comment: Yes 'econ' works too, I don't think it checks the string for content, just the fact that some string is being sent is enough to make it do the compressed version.